# Finding the last person working on a project (grouping/having sql?)

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, having

I'm trying to figure out how to query the last person (name) who last (date) worked on a project (project).

Content TableA

```
     (id) | project  | name     | date
----------+----------+---------------------
        1 | ProjA    | Joe      | 1-1-2011
        2 | ProjA    | Sally    | 2-2-2011
        3 | ProjA    | Joe      | 3-3-2011
        4 | ProjB    | Sally    | 4-4-2011
        5 | ProjB    | Bert     | 5-5-2011
```

What I need to have as a result would be in this case:

```
     (id) | project  | name     | date
----------+----------+-------------
        3 | ProjA    | Joe      | 3-3-2011
        5 | ProjB    | Bert     | 5-5-2011
```

What I've got so far is:

```
SELECT project, max(date) FROM TableA
```

This will get met the project and date but not the id and name of the person.

```
SELECT id, project, name, max(date) FROM TableA
```

This will (obviously) result in the error

> Column 'id' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I'm a bit rusty and lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `row_number()` :

```
select a.*
from (select a.*, row_number() over (partition by a.project order by a.date desc) as seq
      from tablea a
     ) a
where a.seq = 1;
```

If date has *ties*, then you need `dense_rank()` instead.

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for. Will look into dense_rank().

Answer (score 0):

edit:
I now understood correctly but am not sure if this will help. I think it is simpler like this, but might get messy if you have multiple users working on a project on the same day:

```
SELECT project, name, date
FROM (
SELECT *, max_date = MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY project)
FROM TableA) T 
WHERE date = max_date
```

Cheers
Andreas

> Disregard this:
>   I might not understand the question but this should do the tick:
>
> ```
> SELECT id, project, name, max(date) FROM TableA
> GROUP BY id, project, name
> ```

Comment: Hi Andreas, thanks for your answer. This is not resulting in what I was looking for. I'm getting all the record because it is grouped by id.

Comment: Because you have added `name` column in group by clause, it will return all persons name in result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @Temp_Data TABLE
(
    id int ,project varchar(30),[name] varchar(30),[date] date
)

INSERT INTO @Temp_Data
SELECT 1,'ProjA','Joe','1-1-2011' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'ProjA','Sally','2-2-2011' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'ProjA','Joe','3-3-2011' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'ProjB','Sally','4-4-2011' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'ProjB','Bert ','5-5-2011'

;WITH CTE_Temp_Data AS
(
    SELECT id, project,[name],[date],ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project ORDER BY [date] DESC) AS R_NO
    FROM @Temp_Data
)

SELECT id, project,[name],[date] 
FROM CTE_Temp_Data
WHERE R_NO=1
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't mention this in the question but I'll be using the query in a view.